# How do make text in print() and input() appear one by one?

Tags: python, text

Almost like an RPG game, I want to make text appear as if someone is typing them. I have an idea of how to do it with the print() function in python, something involving the sleep() and maybe with sys.stdout.flush?

How would I do it text coming before an input function?

For example, I want `What is your name?` to be typed out, and then the user would input his name.

Comment: what do you mean with the `input` function? The user is putting in the text you can't control his speed. If you mean the message of the `input`, simply print it separatly and then use `input()`

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. What exactly do you want to do with the input function? [For your initial question about the print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896844/how-to-make-python-print-one-character-at-a-time-on-the-same-line)

Comment: Just print the characters one at a time in a loop using `''` for the `end` argument then the line after the loop would be `input()` with no prompt.

Comment: Sorry, the text that comes before the input function, as in x = input('What is your name?')

Comment: `print("What is your name?")` and then `x = input()`

Comment: But then what if I wanted to make a function out of that?

Comment: Sorry, something like: def inputTyping(): and I could call the function every time I wanted the user to input something

Comment: what's the problem, define that function and put those 2 lines inside

Comment: Do you mean something like def inputType(): x = input() print(x)

Comment: Yes, I have answered the question, and put it into a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
text = 'What is your name? '
for x in text:
   sys.stdout.write(x)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(0.00001)
name = input()
```

you can randomize the sleep time per loop as well to mimic typing even better like this:

```
import time,sys,random
text = 'What is your name? '
for x in text:
   sys.stdout.write(x)
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(random.uniform(.000001, .000019))
name = input()
```

as Tomerikoo pointed out, some systems have faster/slow delays so you may need to use uniform(.01, .5) on another system. I use OS/X.

On windows this probably works better. Thanks Tomerikoo:

```
import time,sys,random
text = 'What is your name? '
for x in text:
   print(x, end="", flush=True)
   time.sleep(random.uniform(.000001, .000019))
   # or smaller sleep time, really depends on your system:
   # time.sleep(random.uniform(.01, .5))
name = input()
```

Comment: it depends on your system, you'll definitely need to play around with the values. I'm on  a mac for example, and it prints in real time

Comment: Could also be `print(x, end="", flush=True)` instead of the `sys` calls

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
import time,sys

def getinput(question):
    text = input(question)
    for x in text:
        sys.stdout.write(x)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.00001) #Sets the speed of typing, depending on your system
```

Now everytime you call `getinput("Sample Question")`, you would get the user's input based on the question you passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does this input command work for other questions as well? Would I have to make a def every time asked a new question?

Comment: I have updated my question. Now use `getinput("Question")`. Any question you pass when you call the function will be printed out