# How to print one character at a time but maintain print function -- Python

Tags: python, printing, text-based

I am developing a text-based game on Python and I wanted to have the effect where letters appear one at a time. It has to be a function because I wanted the effect to apply to almost all printed strings. I am using the code seen below, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896844/how-to-make-python-print-one-character-at-a-time-on-the-same-line), and it works fine for this simple example, but the problem is that it does not recognize characters like apostrophes or hyphens and it does not retain the line breaks I have already set up, so it does not work for longer amounts of text.

Is there a way to get around this? If I could have it at least recognize more characters and have it print on a new line every time I use a new slow() function, that would be great.

```
import sys, time    
def slow(text, delay=0.02):
    for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(delay)
    print
slow("Hello!")
```

Thank you and apologize for the beginner question.

Comment: This code absolutely will work on apostrophes.  If you're having trouble with those, then there must be something else wrong.  Please post a full code example that demonstrates an actual problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon is absolutely correct. Also note that *print* on its own is effectively a noop

Comment: @JohnGordon You're right--I realized the text I was trying it on had been copied from something in Microsoft Word, where the apostrophes were formatted differently and the hyphens became em-dashes. Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be done with *print()*

It is a requirement that a newline is output after the individual characters. However, the input string may already end with '\n' so don't repeat it.

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep 

def slow(text, delay=0.1):
    if text: # only process if the string is not zero length
        for c in text:
            print(c, end='', flush=True)
            sleep(delay)
        if text[-1] != '\n':
            print()

slow("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import sys, time     
def slow(text, delay=0.5): 
  for c in text: 
     sys.stdout.write(c) 
     sys.stdout.flush() 
     time.sleep(delay) 
   print('\n')
slow("Hello!\nAlejandra R-")
slow("Hello!\nAlejandra R 2")
```

Comment: This extra logic for '\n' achieves precisely nothing

Comment: That's true, I think it's better that way

Answer (score -2):

```py
import time
def print_one_at_a_time(text, sleep=0.1):
    "print a letter at a time, sleep certain seconds in between"
    text += '\n'
    for c in text:
        print(c, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(sleep)
```

Comment: This does **not** do what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: @Pingu What is OP? and which part am I missing?

Comment: OP == Original Poster - i.e., the person asking the question. The intention is to introduce a delay between the output of each character. As you don't flush the stream then there's no delay

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I don't think the flush is necessary, at least it doesn't make any difference for me. but I explicitly add that to the print. When does that flush to False and flush to True make any difference?@Pingu